# difference between isolated scope + binding name and isolated scope only in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm learning directives in AngularJS, and found that in a few examples, when adding an isolated scope (@, = or &). They sometimes add not only the isolated scope, but also the ngModel name after it. i.e.: "@name" instead of only "@".

So what's the difference between:

```
myApp.directive('zippy', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: { 
            name: "@" // <----
        },
        template: "<div>{{name}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.name);
        }
    }
});
```

And this:

```
myApp.directive('zippy', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: { 
            name: "@name" // <----
        },
        template: "<div>{{name}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.name);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is from the developer guide

> For cases where the attribute name is the same as the value you want
>   to bind to inside the directive's scope, you can use this shorthand
>   syntax:

```
...
scope: {
  // same as '=customer'
  customer: '='
},
...
```

Means you can use `name: "@"` in your directive if your have same name html attribute where directive is declared

```
<div zippy name="myName"></div>
```

Remember attribute name should match not the expression in the attribute. It can be any property on scope.

Comment: Ohhhh i got it... let me rephrase, if instead of name i got "customerName" in the scope, then i should put scope : { customerName: '@name' }, right? but since the scope property is exactly the same as in the directive from the html "name", i don't need to add the "@name", i can use directly "@" :)